# Using Pickle without named references

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to pickle some of my custom classes without any reference to the original class itself.

I tried to modify the original **getstate**() function to just return a dictionary. This solution  looks like  it works, because its just returns a dictionary object, however when I tried to recover it still requires the original class.

This is what I do for getting the object's dictionary:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    odict = self.__dict__.copy()
    return odict
```

And this is my saving code:

```
utils.save_pickle(self.__getstate__(), self.save_path)
```

where save_pickle is just:

```
def save_pickle(obj,name):
    with open(name, 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(obj, handle, protocol=2)
    return
```

However when I tried to unpickle the data, pickle still knows that this is a custom class and uses the **setstate**() function of that class. How can I achieve just to pickle a dictionary and not a reference to class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got your question right. But you always can think classes are dicts:

```py
import pickle


class Desk:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.length = 10
        self.width = 20


desk = Desk("old")

pickled_dict = pickle.dumps(desk.__dict__)
desk= None

# Reassemble
cls_dict = pickle.loads(pickled_dict)
desk = Desk("new")
desk.__dict__.update(cls_dict)
assert desk.name == "old"
```